# UITableview adding white space at top of view

Tags: swift, uitableview

I am running into a weird issue with a tableview adding an empty "white space" at the top.  I have the table view constraint bound to 5 of the segmented control field above.

I am new to Swift and I am not sure how to further debug these types of UI issues.  I have checked the constraints and I do not think that is the issue.  The storyboard does not show this additional white space... where is it coming from?

EDIT: It appears to only create the whitespace on iOS10.  Looks fine on iOS11.

[image: Application home screen]

EDIT: xCode screen

[image: xCode Screen]

Comment: can you add a screen showing the constraint details between table view and segmented control?

Comment: Have you tried my answer? let me know if it works

Comment: @Oxthor screenshot added

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that the automatic content insets on the table view are activated, you can stop this behavior by adding this code to your view controller.

```
  if #available(iOS 11, *) {
     self.tableView.contentInsetAdjustmentBehavior = .never;
  }else{
     self.automaticallyAdjustsScrollViewInsets = false
  }
```

Comment: I changed this to self.tableView.contentInsetAdjustmentBehavior = .never but it did not work

Comment: @Nate23VT are you building the app on ios 11?

Comment: Good point, the iPhone I was testing on is still on 10.3.3.  I checked on an iOS11 device and it does not have this issue.  This is before adding your code

Comment: I receive an error on the iOS11 check - "Expected expression in list of expressions"

Comment: It worked that time, thanks for your help!  The last change did present a new warning though: Unnecessary check for 'iOS'; enclosing scope ensures guard will always be true

Comment: @Nate23VT interesting, I don't get that warning, I am on iOS 11.2

Answer (score 2):

EDIT: I see someone else took my code and got selected already but for the sake of providing full answer here it is.

This behavior is caused by automatic insets by the ios platform. There are two options here:

1. If you snap your table view to bottom edge of navbar be sure to execute the code below. It will disable automatic insets on both iOS 11 and older iOS versions.
2. Otherwise you can snap your tableview to edge of the view and omit the code, because the purpose of the code is to compensate the size of navbar/tabbar, and since you snap your tableview behind/under them, you need that compensation to happen.

Code in case of #1 scenario that works on iOS 11 and older platforms.

Objective-c:

```
if (@available(iOS 11, *)) {
    self.tableView.contentInsetAdjustmentBehavior = UIScrollViewContentInsetAdjustmentNever;
} else {
   self.automaticallyAdjustsScrollViewInsets = NO
}
```

Swift:

```
if #available(iOS 11.0, *) {
    tableView.contentInsetAdjustmentBehavior = .never
} else {
    automaticallyAdjustsScrollViewInsets = false
}
```

Comment: Where in my view controller should I add this code?  I tried it in the ViewDidLoad initially and get several errors: Expected expression in list of expressions, Use of unresolved identifier 'UIScrollViewContentInsetAdjustmentNever', Cannot assign value of type 'ObjCBool' to type 'Bool'

Comment: Are you using swift or objective-c? I'm updating the code snippet above to support both swift and objective-c. viewDidLoad works fine as long as you have tableview set via interface builder or via code before this code :)

Answer (score 0):

Try to look in the 'attribute inspector' (in the right menu) of the Participants ViewController. Check for the option 'Extend Edges' and uncheck the 'Under Top Bars', and then relocate your tableview.

Answer (score 0):

This is the updated 2022 iOS 15 solution

```swift
if #available(iOS 15.0, *) {
    UITableView.appearance().sectionHeaderTopPadding = CGFloat(0)
}
```